# emberjs how to communicate between controller and views?

Tags: ember.js

I manage some shortcuts in the application into the controller. But when the user press an hotkeys combination I need to run a specific method into the a view.

For example when the user press

```
Right arrow
```

I want to leftScroll() my view, but I have an action in the controller

```
actions: {
    rightArrow: function(...) {  }
}
```

How can I call a method into the view?

Answer (score 0):

`this.get('controller')` is how you pick up the corresponding controller in the view, so you would fire it on an action inside `didInsertElement`

e.g.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var controller = this.get('controller');
    $('body').keyDown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
            controller.send('rightArrow');
        }
    });
}
```